# Intellij Git fetch fail for dev.azure.com URL

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-14

My project use dev.azure.com. I can use git clone and fetch with Source Tree. But I cannot use git fetch with Intellij. Intellij show error

```
Fetch Failed Cannot determine the organization name for this 'dev.azure.com' remote URL. Ensure the `credential.useHttpPath` configuration value is set, or set the organization name as the user in the remote URL '{org}@dev.azure.com'. Cannot determine the organization name for this 'dev.azure.com' remote URL. Ensure the `credential.useHttpPath` configuration value is set, or set the organization name as the user in the remote URL '{org}@dev.azure.com'. Authentication failed for
```

[image]

Every thing work ok with Source Tree. How can I resolve this isue for Intellij ?

Comment: Try to enable the `Settings | Version Control | Git | Use credential helper` in IDEA to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue. I change url of azure to

```
https://<my user name>@dev.azure.com/some-url
```